# Continuity of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

I have this function:

$$f(x,y)=\begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{x^2+y^2}{y^2} &if (x,y)\neq 0) \\0 
 &if (x,y)=0) 
\end{Bmatrix}$$

I am asked to evaluate the continuity. I replaced 'y' by 'mx', then i found that it is not continuous at (0,0). But what about when it's not (0,0), if y=0 but not x, the function is undefined, does that count as not continuous?

Thank you

Comment: Your definition of $f$ needs restating.

Answer (score 1):

In order for $f$ to be continuous we need $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=C$$ to be independent of our choice of path.

Consider the line where $y=x.$ Here we have $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,x)\to (0,0)}f(x,x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+x^2}{x^2}=2.$$

And if we consider the line where $x=0$ we have $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{(0,y)\to (0,0)}f(0,y)=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{0^2+y^2}{y^2}=1.$$

Thus $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0).$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. An undefined function cannot be continuous. If you do not own a cat, can it be brown?

Now if the question is : is it continuous on its domain then the answer might differ.

Comment: what i meant was, since we are evaluating at $(x,y)\neq 0$, am i allowed to have y=0 if $x\neq 0$, but yeah what i'm asking is, is it continuous on it's domain

Comment: (x,0) are all not on the domain if x is not 0.